# Markov Chain, finding the steady state vector

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Suppose that if it is sunny today, there is a 60% chance that it will be sunny tomorrow, a
30% chance that it will be partly cloudy and a 10% chance that it will be completely cloudy.
If it is partly cloudy today, there is a 40% chance that it will be sunny tomorrow and a 30%
chance that it will be partly cloudy. If it is completely cloudy today, there is a 40% chance that it will be sunny tomorrow and a 50% chance that it will be partly cloudy.

Determine in the long term, what is the probability that it will be sunny in the next day.

I used the information above to create a stochastic matrix that is:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.6 & 0.4&0.4\\0.3&0.3&0.5\\0.1&0.3&0.1\end{bmatrix}$$

How would I determine the steady-state vector from this matrix?

Answer (score 0):

So far you have constructed a *table*, not a matrix.  Your table does not become a matrix until there is a significance to matrix multiplication.

Let $S_n$ be the probability that it is **s**unny on day $n$.

Let $P_n$ be the probability that it is **p**artly cloudy on day $n$

Let $C_n$ be the probability that it is completely **c**loudy on day $n$.

Suppose that you know $S_k$, $P_k$, and $C_k$.  Find a formula, for example, for the probability that it is sunny the next day:

$$S_{k+1} = A_{s \to s}S_k + A_{p \to s}P_k + A_{c \to s}C_k \tag{A}$$

where $A_{x \to y}$ is the probability that the weather transitions from $x$ to $y$.  Formula **(A)** should look like something to you from forlorn memories of  linear algebra lectures.

This should allow to write the weather of one day in terms of the weather of a previous day using linear algebra.  Then extrapolate to infinity.